# Finding first element of a Mathematica list greater than a threshold

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was wondering how I could obtain the first element of a (already ordered) list that is greater than a given threshold.

I don't know really well the list manipulation function in Mathematica, maybe someone can give me a trick to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html) does what you need, and will be consistent, respecting the pre-existing order of the list:

```
Select[list, # > threshold &, 1]
```

For example:

```
In[1]:= Select[{3, 5, 4, 1}, # > 3 &, 1]

Out[1]= {5}
```

You can provide whatever threshold or criterion function you need in the second argument.

The third argument specifies you only one (i.e., the first) element that matches.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

Joe correctly states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671937/finding-first-element-of-a-mathematica-list-greater-than-a-threshold/7056889#7056889) that one would expect a binary search technique to be faster than `Select`, which seem to just do a linear search even if the list is sorted:

```
ClearAll[selectTiming]
selectTiming[length_, iterations_] := Module[
    {lst},
    lst = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, length]];
    (Do[Select[lst, # == 2 &, 1], {i, 1, iterations}] // Timing // 
     First)/iterations
  ]
```

[image]

(I arbitrarily put the threshold at 2 for demonstration purposes).

However, the `BinarySearch` function in Combinatorica is a) not appropriate (it returns an element which does match the requested one, but not the first (leftmost), which is what the question is asking.

To obtain the leftmost element that is larger than a threshold, given an ordered list, we may proceed either recursively:

```
binSearch[lst_,threshold_]:= binSearchRec[lst,threshold,1,Length@lst]

(*
return position of leftmost element greater than threshold
breaks if the first element is greater than threshold
lst must be sorted
*)
binSearchRec[lst_,threshold_,min_,max_] :=
    Module[{i=Floor[(min+max)/2],element},
        element=lst[[i]];
        Which[
            min==max,max,
            element <= threshold,binSearchRec[lst,threshold,i+1,max],
            (element > threshold) && ( lst[[i-1]] <= threshold ), i,
            True, binSearchRec[lst,threshold,min,i-1]
        ]
    ]
```

or iteratively:

```
binSearchIterative[lst_,threshold_]:=Module[
    {min=1,max=Length@lst,i,element},
    While[
        min<=max,
        i=Floor[(min+max)/2];
        element=lst[[i]];
        Which[
            min==max, Break[],
            element<=threshold, min=i+1,
            (element>threshold) && (lst[[i-1]] <= threshold), Break[],
            True, max=i-1
        ]
    ];
    i
]
```

The recursive approach is clearer but I'll stick to the iterative one.

To test its speed,

```
ClearAll[binSearchTiming]
binSearchTiming[length_, iterations_] := Module[
    {lst},
    lst = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, length]];
    (Do[binSearchIterative[lst, 2], {i, 1, iterations}] // Timing // 
     First)/iterations
  ]
```

which produces

[image]

so, much faster and with better scaling behaviour.

Actually it's not necessary to compile it but I did anyway.

In conclusion, then, don't use `Select` for long lists.

This concludes my answer. There follow some comments on doing a binary search by hand or via the Combinatorica package.

I compared the speed of a (compiled) short routine to do binary search vs the `BinarySearch` from `Combinatorica`. Note that this does not do what the question asks (and neither does `BinarySearch` from `Combinatorica`); the code I gave above does.

The binary search may be implemented iteratively as

```
binarySearch = Compile[{{arg, _Integer}, {list, _Integer, 1}},
           Module[ {min = 1, max = Length@list,
                 i, x},
               While[
                    min <= max,
                    i = Floor[(min + max)/2];
                    x = list[[i]];
                    Which[
                         x == arg, min = max = i; Break[],
                         x < arg, min = i + 1,
                         True, max = i - 1
                     ]
                ];
               If[ 0 == max,
                   0,
                   max
               ]
           ], 
        CompilationTarget -> "C", 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

and we can now compare this and `BinarySearch` from `Combinatorica`. Note that a) the list must be sorted b) this will not return the *first* matching element, but *a* matching element.

```
lst = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 1000000]];
```

Let us compare the two binary search routines. Repeating 50000 times:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Do[binarySearch[2, lst], {i, 50000}] // Timing
Do[BinarySearch[lst, 2], {i, 50000}] // Timing
(*
{0.073437, Null}
{4.8354, Null}
*)
```

So the handwritten one is faster. Now since in fact a binary search just visits 6-7 points in the list for these parameters (something like `{500000, 250000, 125000, 62500, 31250, 15625, 23437}` for instance), clearly the difference is simply overhead; perhaps `BinarySearch` is more general, for instance, or not compiled.

Comment: Looking at the source code of `BinarySearch` (which is available because it is in an add-on package, in the file AddOns\Packages\Combinatorica\Combinatorica.m in the Mathematica installation folder) the code is almost identical to your `binarySearch` function. This makes me wonder if the improved performance is only due the compiled code. Maybe you should try compiling `BinarySearch` and then testing it for speed?

Comment: @Joe you are right, I had the impression that the source was not longer available in v8 so I did not look for it. It does appear that the only difference is due to compilation.

Comment: Good stuff. I wasn't aware of this answer (and question, as well). +1.

Comment: Word of warning for copy-paste programmers: at least `binSearchIterative` gets stuck in infinite loop in case threshold is smaller than the first list element. Easy fix is checking for that in the function before the loop.

Comment: The problem is not in the algorithm but I would call it a bug. It happens when in`lst[[i-1]]` index gets `0` and the whole `Which` will not be evaluated. The same thing effects the recursive implementation.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at TakeWhile[] and LengthWhile[] as well.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TakeWhile.html
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LengthWhile.html

Answer (score 3):

Using `Select` will solve the problem, but it is a poor solution if you care about efficiency. `Select` goes over all the elements of the list, and therefore will take time which is linear in the length of the list.

Since you say the list is ordered, it is much better to use [`BinarySearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/BinarySearch.html), which will work in a time which is logarithmic in the size of the list. The expression (**edit**: I have made a small adjustment since the previous expression I wrote did not handle correctly recurring elements in the list. **another edit**: this still doesn't work when the threshold itself appears in the list as a recurring element, see comments):

```
Floor[BinarySearch[list,threshold]+1]
```

will give you the index of the desired element. If all the elements are smaller than the threshold, you'll get the length of the list plus one.
p.s. don't forget to call `Needs["Combinatorica'"]` before using `BinarySearch`.

Comment: Why do you need Ceiling? Also, this does not return the first (leftmost) matching element. I wrote something that does obtain the leftmost element using a binary search in my answer.

Comment: I changed the `Ceiling` function to a `Floor` function to correctly handle recurring elements in the list. It is needed because if the threshold is between elements _n_ and _n+1_ then `BinarySearch` returns _n+1/2_. The code I wrote works perfectly, and does indeed return the first (leftmost) element which is **greater than the threshold** (the request was not for a matching element). It is also **much** simpler than the code @acl provided in his answer.

Comment: strange, here, `lst = {1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5};
Floor[BinarySearch[lst, 3] + 1]` gives 6, and lst[[6]] isn't greater than the threshold but is the same as the `binarySearch` routine I give below would obtain (which however is around 50 times faster). The complicated code in my answer is just binary search with a slightly modified termination condition (so as to actually obtain the leftmost element larger than the threshold). Or at least it mostly does correctly find the right element :)

Comment: You are right @acl, sorry for doubting you. In the case when the threshold appears in the list as a recurring element `BinarySearch` gives an index from the middle of the recurring sequence, which is no good. It's too bad we have to write our own version of a function Mathematica already provides, only because it doesn't give us control over the termination condition.

Comment: thanks for the vote. It is even more of a shame that even if one needs exactly what `BinarySearch` does, writing it by hand and compiling makes it so much faster. But perhaps this is so because of `BinarySearch` being part of `Combinatorica`, rather than a built-in function.

Answer (score 3):

```
list /. {___, y_ /; y > 3, ___} :> {y}
```

For example

```
{3, 5, 4, 1} /. {___, y_ /; y > 3, ___} :> {y}

{5}
```

Comment: Very clever but try `tmp = Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 100000]];` then `tmp /. {___, y_ /; y > 3, ___} :> {y} // Timing`; ouch! Still, +1 for elegance

Comment: @Aci.  Tried that.  You are right. Ouch! (I suppose this is caused by the conditional?)

Comment: Apparently, but who knows why. If I use `{___, 3, ___} :> {3}` the time taken goes up linearly with the list length, if I use your form, quadratically.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, starting from *v10*  you can use [`SelectFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectFirst.html)

It has some added niceties, such as returning `Missing[]` or default values.

From the docs:

> `SelectFirst[{e1,e2,…}, crit]` gives the first `ei` for which `crit[ei]` is `True`, or `Missing["NotFound"]` if none is found.
>
> `SelectFirst[{e1,e2,…}, crit, default]` gives `default` if there is no `ei` such that `crit[ei]` is `True`.

For your specific case, you would use:

```
SelectFirst[list, # > threshold &]
```