# manipulate list in mathematica with select

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have imported some data into Mathematica. The data will look similar to

```
{{0,2},{2,3},{4,3},{5,4},{8,4}}
```

I want to throw out all elements for which the x-values are smaller than a given value or create a new list that contains the data for which the x-values are larger than this value. I assume that *Select* should do the job but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
 data = {{0,2},{2,3},{4,3},{5,4},{8,4}};
 filtered = Select[data, First[#]>3&];
```

where you replace 3 with your given value?

Comment: @Lucas, `Select` accepts any boolean function as its second parameter, so you can specify anything you can conceive of.  For instance, you could eliminate all of the pairs that are within some distance, `d`, of the origin via `Norm[#] < d&`, for instance. It is extremely flexible.  Also, see this previous question for other ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671937/finding-first-element-of-a-mathematica-list-greater-than-a-threshold

Comment: an alternative to what @karsten posted would be `filtered = Select[data,#[[1]]>3&]`. This way, you may expand to any element of the list: e.g. selecting the 5th element `filtered = Select[data,#[[5]]>3&]`

Answer (score 3):

Another versatile approach is to use Cases and attach a condition (/;)

For example:

data = {{0, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {8, 4}};
Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x > 3]

or attach a condition as follows (for example):

Cases[data, {x_ /; x > 3, _}]

(The approach will also  work with DeleteCases)