# Select[nested_list, condition] in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements, nested-lists

Let's say I have a list:

```
list=Table[{RandomReal[],RandomReal[],RandomReal[]}, {i,1,100}];
```

I'd like to make a new list based on conditions. Now I've seen that I should use the `Select` function, but I don't understand how to define the condition where selection should be based on some element of nested list. 
Someone asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118474/manipulate-list-in-mathematica-with-select) and the answer I like was:

```
data = {{0,2},{2,3},{4,3},{5,4},{8,4}};
filtered = Select[data, First[#]>3&];
```

However this only works if the condition is set on first element of sublist. In my case:

```
Select[list,0.2>First[#]>0.1&]
```

gives all members of the list where 1. element of sublist is between 0.1 and 0.2. But what if I wanted to make selection based on a second element of a sublist, or in general for the nth element? 
Also an example with combination of elements would be nice, for example where the sum of first 2 elements of sublist is smaller than 0.5.

Comment: Please verify the link to the previous question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, generating the list is easier as:

```
list = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];
```

You can use [`Part` (see the docs!!)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html), which is equivalent to the `[[ ]]` syntax, to take the `n`th element.  E.g. this selects those items which have a second element larger than 0.1.

```
Select[list, #[[2]] > 0.1 &]
```

Alternatively use

```
Cases[list, l_ /; l[[2]] > 0.1]
```

or

```
Cases[list, {_, y_, _} /; y > 0.1]
```

I recommend you explore the tutorials in the documentation, especially the part about [list manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html).